# How to get python to automatically write and save files

Tags: python

Is it possible to write a code in python that saves and writes files automatically?

How I want the code to work:
The user opens the program. The program asks for an input, lets say it asks for the users name. User inputs his name. The program then takes that name and writes it in an external file and saves. The user then closes the program. Next time the program is opened it imports the external file, thus knowing the name of the user.

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried, and why is its behaviour not what you want? Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @Braiam this wasn't a worthwhile edit. Removing a tag and a sign off on a bad question that's over a year old just adds noise to people's main pages because any recently edited question is bumped to the top of the "active" lists.

Comment: @AdamSmith well, it got an answer. It was a worthy edit. If you believe that the question is subpar, then vote to close.

Comment: @Braiam it got a bad code-only answer, as it's a bad no-code question. It should be closed and deleted, which would have happened automatically had it not been bumped. The signal to noise ratio is actually worsened by this (since both question and answer are noise. The only person the answer might have helped is the OQA, who is certainly not still waiting for an answer)

Comment: It also sent the bad answers to the late answer queue, further wasting the community's time.

Comment: @Braiam "This should have been done a year ago, so I'm going to do it now even though it's harmful to everyone" is not really reasonable. This isn't a case of "The best time to remove a tag is a year ago, the second best time is now" unless the tag was being burninated. It isn't (as you know since you're participating in that conversation on Meta)

Answer (score -3):

Yes of corse this are here a same introduction with some lines

```
import os


def write_to_file(name):
    text_file = open("%s.txt"% name , "w")
    text_file.write("%s" % name)
    text_file.close()

def check_exists(name):
    if os.path.exists("./"+name+".txt"):
        print "File found!"
    else:
        write_to_file(name)


def input_name():
    return(raw_input("input name: "))


check_exists(input_name())
```